# PHP: How to get an array's value by its numeric offset if it's an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array which when var dumped looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [tumblr] => Array
        (
            [type] => tumblr
            [url] => http://tumblr.com/
        )

    [twitter] => Array
        (
            [type] => twitter
            [url] => https://twitter.com/
        )

)
```

As you can see the key's are custom "tumblr" and "twitter" and not numeric 0 and 1.

Some times I need to get the values by the custom keys and sometimes I need to get values by numeric keys.

Is there anyy way I can get `$myarray[0]` to output:

```
(
    [type] => tumblr
    [url] => http://tumblr.com/
)
```

Comment: Numeric and string keys are not interchangeable in PHP. Can you describe more what you need?

Comment: All arrays in PHP are associative, even the numerically indexed ones.  This means that if you assign a string as the index, there is no associated numerical value.  @nickb has a nice way to deal with this below.

Comment: @Michael don't even ask, working with someone else's code and don't feel like rewriting the whole thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run the array through [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values):

```
$myarray = array_values( $myarray);
```

Now your array looks like:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "tumblr"
    ["url"]=>
    string(18) "http://tumblr.com/"
  } ...
```

This is because `array_values()` will only grab the values from the array and reset / reorder / rekey the array as a numeric array.

Comment: `$myarray+=array_values($myarray);` would create an array that could use both named and numeric indexes, much the same way mysql_fetch_array works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to get a copy of the array with numeric indexes.